# Difference between Gdx.graphics.getWidth() and camera.viewportWidth

Tags: android, libgdx

I am a newbie in game development and I am developing an android game using Libgdx on `intelliJ` IDE.
I want to understand the difference between `Gdx.graphics.getWidth()` and `camera.viewportWidth` .
As I want the size of everything (example buttons) in my game to be by percentage of width and height of the screen, so what should I use for that `Gdx.graphics.getWidth()` or `camera.viewportWidth` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Gdx.graphics.getWidth()` gives you the width in pixels of the either the window (in desktop mode) or the screen (for IOS or Android).

`viewportWidth` on the `Camera` is the span in *world-units* that the camera can see.

If you set every size up to be a percentage of the screen size then you can use any of the two.

Based on a guess of what you're trying to achieve I think a `ScreenViewport` would work well for you, but note that you might run into issues with aspect ratio as not all devices have screens in the same aspect ratio.

There's [good documentation about viewports](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports) available at the **libGDX** wiki.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about aspect ratio . Can you please tell me what can I use to maintain the aspect ratio ?

Comment: @ZaidQureshi click the link in his post. It talks about viewports and maintaining aspect ratio.